# Popover from UI Button to display Text

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I'm attempting to make a Popover similar to the one seen here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RihT.png

This popover is meant to be an IBAction from the button, which in this image is titled: "Ventral Primary Ramus". I've looked around the internet for tutorials and I have mainly seen tutorials on creating popovers from the UIBarButtonItem. For this popover as you can see I need to be able to title it, as well as in then display text information about the structure who's button was pressed. Along those same lines how would I go about making sure that the window will auto-fit to the text?

Answer (score 0):

There is many tutorials for this. For example:
[appcoda](http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/)
[raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29472/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uipopovercontroller-tutorial)
It's really easy to present some popover, just read this.